# THREE.JS: Unable to load image onto a ImageCanvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

Tried to make a cube with different images on each side, however, is unable to load it successfully.

Tried the commented out method and the method below, both did not work.

```
function createImageCanvas(img, showOnBothSides){ 
    // var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(img.src);
    // texture.anisotropy = renderer.capabilities.getMaxAnisotropy();
    // texture.needsUpdate = true;
    if(showOnBothSides)
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({transparent: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide }); 
    else
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({transparent: true });
    console.log(img);
    var img = "images/layers.png";
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
        // resource URL
        img,
        // Function when resource is loaded
        function ( texture ) {
            // do something with the texture
                material.map = texture; // set the material's map when when the texture is loaded
        },
        // Function called when download progresses
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
        },
        // Function called when download errors
        function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
        }
    );
    return material;
}
```

Console log:

```
index.html:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://threejs.org/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

Comment: Can you please try to demonstrate the issue with a live example (e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/). Be aware that `ImageUtils` is deprecated and should not be used anymore. The replacement is `TextureLoader`. Besides, when loading a texture with `TextureLoader`, you don't have to manually set `Texture.needsUpdate` to `true`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your console message is likely because you are referencing three.js from threejs.org. Try changing your reference to use one of teh versions hosted on [cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/three.js/), or download and host three.js alongside your HTML.